# Stop Watin Testing procedure

Tags: watin

Once we have launched watin testing procedure and IE opens and automation is on the way is there any way to interrupt that process?

Or
as we implement watin in threaded enviourment so is there any way to have information of thread running and we can terminate that thread?

Lets say we ave started thread for testing website1 , website2 and website 3 so if we want to stop automated testing  for website1 I should interrupt it and make it stop where ever it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Browser.Close and then cacth the exception `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`

I mean you could do

```
public class Test
{
    public void Main()
    {

        // Create the three browser.
        Browser browser1 = new Browser();
        Browser browser2 = new Browser();
        Browser browser3 = new Browser();

        // Start the test.
        new Thread(() => doTest(test1, browser1)).Start();
        new Thread(() => doTest(test2, browser2)).Start();
        new Thread(() => doTest(test3, browser3)).Start();

        // interrupt test 1
        browser1.Close();
    }

    private doTest(Action<Browser> test, Browser browser)
    {
        try
        {
            // do the test
            test(browser);
        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
        {
            // test was interrupted
        }
    }

    private void test1(Browser browser)
    {
    }

    private void test2(Browser browser)
    {
    }

    private void test3(Browser browser)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: but i dont know how many browsers will be created I create browsers within the defination of thread

Comment: What do you mean ? Do you mean that you don't have access to the browser outside the threads ? It should not be a problem to make them accessible. Could you edit your initial question and show some code ?